# How to sum and pivot a table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

| col_a | col_b | col_c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |

I want to sum up each column and assign a value to it based on the output, with the output like-so below:

| column | sum | string |
| --- | --- | --- |
| col_a | 1 | 'string one' |
| col_b | 1 | 'string two' |
| col_b | 1 | 'string three' |

I've tried the following SQL:

```
SELECT
SUM(col_a) AS sum_a,
SUM(col_b) AS sum_b,
SUM(col_c) AS sum_c
FROM table
```

This gives me three total columns, but I've been unable to figure out the rest.

Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you know all column names upfront?

Comment: where does "string" column come from?

Comment: You have no column or row `string` - and your desired results has two `col_b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really want to unpivot. I typically use cross apply for that.

```
select ca.key,SUM(ca.pair)
from table
cross apply(values('col_a',col_a),('col_b',col_b),('col_c',col_c)) ca(key,pair)
group by ca.key
```

I don't understand your string column.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you. Oh, that third 'string' column is just to add a description for the row. But I see why you didn't get my string column, now that I look at it I don't get it either.

Comment: @Thien-AnDoan Please accept answer to close out this question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to first sum, *then* unpivot:

```sql
select ca.[column], ca.[sum]
from (
    SELECT
        SUM(col_a) AS sum_a,
        SUM(col_b) AS sum_b,
        SUM(col_c) AS sum_c
    FROM [table]
) t
cross apply (values
    ('col_a', sum_a),
    ('col_b', sum_b),
    ('col_c', sum_c)
) ca([column], [sum])
```